# Boolean operations AND

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

When the $\times$ sign means AND, the possible results are

1. 0 × 0 = 0
2. 0 × 1 = 0
3. 1 × 0 = 0
4. 1 × 1 = 1

In other words, the result is 1 only if both the left operand AND the right
operand are 1.

This is axiom?

Comment: do you mean axiom???

Comment: We'd rather say that it is the *definition* of the operator.

Comment: An axiom is a statement accepted without evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to explain what an axiom is:

An axiom is a statement that is treated as true without proof.

These are the assumed premises that you start with to make logical conclusions.  What you have there is not an axiom. It's an operation $\times$ which you have defined as the construct AND.

The reason it's not an axiom is that we are restricting an action. In this case we are setting $\times$ as a valid operation within the Boolean algebraic structure we've built. This way if someone tries to use $\times$ they won't come up and say $0\times 0=1$.

By the way you can define $\times$ such that $0\times 0=1$ would be true.

Answer (score 3):

What you've written (the truth-table for the AND-connective, essentially) and your summary is correct, but it expresses the **definition** of AND, but it is **not** an axiom.  The four assignments you show **define** precisely when $a\times b$ (and in this case $a\land b$) is true, and when it is false.

Similarly, we define the **inclusive** OR as follows

1. 1+1 = 1
2. 1+0 = 1
3. 0+1 = 1
4. 0+0 = 0

Whenever at least one of the disjuncts is 1, then the disjunction is 1.

---

The Exclusive Or: a XOR b is defined such that when one and only one of a, b is true, then a XOR B = 1.

This gives us:

1 XOR 1 = 0

1 XOR 0 = 1

0 XOR 1 = 1

0 XOR 0 = 0

Comment: On what this definition is based?

Comment: It's how we define  $\land$, or $\lor$.  (Just as we define, say $A\subseteq B$ to mean $a \in A \rightarrow a\in B$, and use it consistently.)

Comment: Suppose  it is claimed that Jack is your friend and John is your friend.$$ $$  If you are friends with neither, you can judge that claim false. $(0\times 0 = 0)$ $$ $$  If you are friends with Jack, but not John, you can judge the that claim false. $(1 \times 0 = 0)$ $$ $$ If you are not friends with jack, but you **are** friends with John, you can conclude the claim was false. $(0\times 1 = 0)$ $$ $$ Finally, if you are friends with BOTH Jack and John, the claim is true. $(1\times 1 = 1)$ $$$$